# default configuration about 'spark.shuffle.consolidatefiles'

Tags: apache-spark

what is the default behavior to Map Shuffling in the newer version of Spark?

I learned that configuration of spark.shuffle.consolidateFile is used to reduce memory cost by write buffer. But I cannot find the configuration anymore. I checked configuration, and from Spark 1.6.0, this configuration has been removed. So what is the default behavior to Map Shuffling in the newer version of Spark?

Answer (score 1):

I learned that hash shuffle has been replaced by sort shuffle. So this configuration makes no sense anymore.